# Box on left being pushed downwards

Tags: html, css, positioning

I am trying to position two `<div>`s within each other, but it seems when I input text into the `<div>` on the left side, it gets pushed down. It's almost like there is an element above it, but there is no object there, while the one it is supposed to be inline with stays in the right place.

HTML code:

```
<div id="header_div">

 <div id="header_div_left">Home</div>

 <div id="header_div_right"></div>

</div>
```

CSS code:

```
#header_div {
    width: 980px;
    height: 125px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #A5A5A5;
    background-color: #191919;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-top: 4px solid #E00000;
}

#header_div_left {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 290px;
    height: 120px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    line-height: 120px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid #A5A5A5;
    background-color: #191919;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

#header_div_right {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 655px;
    height: 120px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    border: 2px solid #A5A5A5;
    background-color: #191919;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9wCnu/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `vertical-align:top` to the inner divs.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Wmb4G/)**

Since you set the inner divs to have an inline-block display, you want to align them to the top of their parent div.

Answer (score 0):

Add to each divs css

```
position:relative;
float:left;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MkEWp/

Answer (score 0):

Add `float:left` to the left div.

Answer (score 0):

Put text in both of them (even if it's just a `&nbsp;`) and set their `line-height` to be the same.

http://jsfiddle.net/9wCnu/1/